# Is there any way to get statistics by tag?

Tags: support, api, statistics

We are Stack Overflow Teams users. We want to get the statistics by tags.
Currently only `StackExchangeApiClient.getStatistics` API is found which include all team's data.

And can the `https://stackoverflow.com/c/xxxx/metrics-dashboard` page be parameterized to support filter by tags?

Answer (score 3):

At this point our API only offers the following reading capabilities around tags:

[image]

(https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)

Unfortunately, the Dashboard can't be filtered to Tags.

Comment: is that possible to use bigquery like this: https://preset.io/blog/2020-10-08-bigquery-superset-part-2/ to get team specific data and work out dashboard separately?

Comment: or have to work out by ourselves: https://github.com/robnyman/stackoverflow-dashboard