# (Should we) add [Staff] labels to staff member flairs?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, users, flair, staff

[This answer](https://stackapps.com/a/9376/34061) is posted by a staff member, but you have to go to the [user's profile](https://stackapps.com/users/82413/hannah-schepers) to actually see that.

Can we add [Staff] labels to staff member flairs like on [all meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367846/295232)? [♦ Mod] labels aren't necessary IMHO, rene and I are just experienced users of the API, nothing more.

Comment: I confirm I did visit the user profile as well for the exact same reason.

Comment: Agreed, that sounds quite useful here as staff often act as an authoritative source on API matters.

Comment: Agreed that this seems useful.  On other Meta sites, I believe the Mods can add the [tag:status-review] tag to a Meta post for Staff to review a change request.  Does that work here, or perhaps not since this isn't considered a Meta site?  Not sure.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds that would work, but it feels rather strange to put a [status-review] on my own request. Of course I can ask rene :)

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds StackApps is a little special (in a good sense of the word) in that regards - kind of like MSE, the mod-only tags are present despite this not being a Meta site.

Comment: Just confirming that the status-review tag on this post did add it to our radar. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tada!  This was an easy change on our end, it turns out we already had functionality to turn this on for individual sites. Our code doesn't define Stack Apps as a Meta site so Stack Apps doesn't get it by default, it's a special case.

Comment: Dang it, now I have to self-destroy the comment about the irony :) Joking aside, thank you!

Comment: I'll make sure to code in a special case to our special case so that the joke is preserved  `bool IsMetaSite => IsChildMeta || IsMetaStackExchange || (IsStackApps && question.Id != 9377)`

Comment: xD just happy to see such a quick turnaround on StackApps requests lately - thanks again!

Comment: Happy to hear that - I love how the `[status-review]` tag gets it triaged and in front of us so quickly.

Comment: Always nice to be able to verify that it works at the very place one asked for it. Thanks for the quick fix!

Answer (score 5):

This request will be [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) and we hope to have this completed in the near term in a future sprint.

Comment: Oh, the irony of staff not being displayed as staff :) Thanks for working on it!